# Summing two ints in a list python

Tags: python, list

So I'm a Python noobie and I figured a good way to learn the language is go through some problems on leetcode using it.

The first problem is "Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target." I coded up a solution fairly quickly in java, but when I tried implementing it in Python the values I get back leave me scratching my head. Given the input [3, 2, 4] and a target of 6, it should return back [1, 2], but currently it is returning [0, 1]

Python:

```
class Solution():
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
            for j, num2 in enumerate(nums, i + 1):

                if (num1 + num2 == target):
                    return [i, j]
```

Java:

```
class Solution {
    public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int sum = nums[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (sum + nums[j] == target) {
                    return new int[] {i, j};
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why I am getting this result back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional second argument to `enumerate` doesn't do what you think it does.  It looks like your intent was to have it use that as a starting point in the list.  But what it actually does is use it as the starting point for numbering the list elements, i.e. it is the value that is associated with the first element of the list.  For example:

```
>>> list(enumerate(["a", "b", "c"], 5))
[(5, 'a'), (6, 'b'), (7, 'c')]
>>>
```

So in your case, the outer loop is numbering the elements 0, 1, and 2.  The inner loop is iterating over all three elements, but is numbering them 1, 2, 3.  The first iteration of each loop is extracting the value 3 from the list, and 3+3 matches, with num1 being 0 and num2 being 1.

Answer (score 1):

Second argument of `enumerate()` in Python is not doing what you think it's doing. Instead of affecting which element of the list it starts on, it merely affects the index that it returns.

What you should be doing is: `for j, num2 in enumerate(nums[i + 1:], i + 1):`

What this does is it uses Python's slicing to drop the first `i` elements from the list and then adjusts the index in the second argument of `enumerate()` to produce correct output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range based for loop to do it as you did in Java.

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        sum = nums[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
            if (sum + nums[j] == target):
                return [i, j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use range based for loop instead:

```
class Solution():
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):

                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target):
                    return [i, j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a working example:

```
class Solution():
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
            for j, num2 in enumerate(nums):
                if (j>i and (num1 + num2) == target):
                    return [i, j]
        return "Not found"


print(Solution().twoSum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 10)) # [1, 7]
print(Solution().twoSum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 22)) # Not found
print(Solution().twoSum([8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 10)) # [0, 6]
print(Solution().twoSum([8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 22)) # Not found
```

Your mistake was that as you can read from the documentation [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) you misinterpreted the second parameter in the `enumerate` function. What it actually does is to set a starting point for a counter. If we don't set anythin it will start from 0 abd this will be equal to the index.